# How to pass parameter in Express API with NuxtJs project?

Tags: express, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I building project NuxtJs + ExpressJs(SSR type) with options as below

[image]

**In file `server/index.js` i import API route**

```
const express = require('express')
const consola = require('consola')
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const api = require("./routes/routes.js")(app, fs);

// Import API route
app.use('/api', api);
// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

async function start () {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

  const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server

  await nuxt.ready()
  // Build only in dev mode
  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt)
    await builder.build()
  }

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render)

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host)
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true
  })
}
start()
```

**In `routes/routes.js`**

```
// import other routes
const productRoutes = require("./product/products.js");

const appRouter = (app, fs) => {
  // default route
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("welcome to the development api-server");
  });

  // // other routes
  productRoutes(app, fs);
};

module.exports = appRouter;
```

**And in `product/products.js`**

```
const productRoutes = (app, fs) => {
    app.get("/products", (req, res) => {});
    app.post("/products", (req, res) => {});
    app.put("/products/:id", (req, res) => {});
    app.delete("/products/:id", (req, res) => {});
};
module.exports = productRoutes;
```

However, i have error `TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function`. Maybe i cannot pass parameter `(app, fs)` when using `app.use('/api', api)` and need to handle Middleware.
I'm newbie with ExpressJs and Middleware. I don't know what i'm missing. I hope someone please give me a solution. Thanks very much.

Comment: hi, i tried following you but it hasn't worked yet

Comment: Is there any reason to pass a parameter `(app, fs)` in your `product/products.js`?

Comment: yes, i want to use them for handles in routes api

Comment: you can see i use them in `product/products.js`